# regex - matching lines with and operator

Tags: regex

I have some text:

> The great red fox. Which are not blue foxes. But foxes which are red are not any more faster.

Basically I want to match sentences where "red" and "fox" both appear in that order and another regex where it is not in that order.

How would I do that ?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: also - regexs aren't QUITE the same in each language - is there a specific language you are using?

Comment: yeah, trying in Javscript. I know how to use "|" but that is like or operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is no abbreviations with dots in your sentences:

for any order:

```
(?=[^.!?]*fox)(?=[^.!?]*red)[^.!?]+[.!?]
```

for "red" before "fox":

```
[^.!?]*?red[^.!?]+?fox[^.!?]*[.!?]
```

Comment: This is best answer so far - but what is a sentence ends with a ? or ! - hehe

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: Indeed <°)))))))))>

Comment: IMHO it is almost impossible to break a paragraph into sentence. How about `Robert Jr. is a good fellow.`

Comment: ACTUALLY - the extra lgoic needed (assuming proper grammar) is just .?!\s[A-Z] - but the answer above is worthy of my +1

Comment: @anubhava: Yes, I think too.

Answer (score 1):

For "red" following "fox":

```
\b[^.?!]+red.*?fox[.?!]+
```

for "fox" following "red":

```
\b[^.?!]+fox.*?red[.?!]+
```

to capture all other sentences except ones have "red" following "fox":

```
(?:\b[^.?!]+red.*?fox[.?!]+)(.*?[.?!]+)
```

as you work with Javascript don't forget to put `g` modifier to capture all occurrences:

```
/\b[^.?!]+red.*?fox[.?!]+/g
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/iB9dS1)

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming each sentence appears in a separate line* you can do:

> `I want to match sentences where "red", "fox" both appears in that order`

You can use:

```
^.*?red.*?fox.*$
```

> `I want to match sentences where "red", "fox" both appears in ANY order`

You can use `positive lookahead`:

```
^(?=.*?red)(?=.*?fox).*$
```

Comment: You are assuming the input data has already been broken up into sentences, which the OP does not indicate specifically is the case.

Comment: great answer but...... how do we know it is a sentence? that will match all 3 sentences

Comment: Yes this is for validating a single line of string. If there are multiple lines to validate then I would suggest using `/m` switch.

Comment: Nor does he say anything about the input being broken up into lines.  I think he is working with a paragraph of text that has no linebreaks, and wants to isolate sentences within the paragraph that match certain patterns.

Comment: @MikeClark: Please see my comment on the other answer about breaking a paragraph into each sentence using regex.